# News Feed? Activity?: What are some ways to represent this term as an icon?

Tags: icon, interface-design

I'm working with a team on an app that deals with events(conventions, meetups, weddings, etc) and travel. The closest competitor would be [Epilogger.](http://epilogger.com/)

One section in this app is called Activity(ies). The content in here is fairly identical with Facebook's News Feed, or any other social media's content feed. Its basically a list of items(photos and comments) posted by users during an event.

I am having a hard time conceptualizing an icon for this. I'm not sure what I want but I know what I don't want: newspaper, pulse, or any specific activity. I'd love some guidance or any input on the matter.

So my question is "What are some ways to represent this term as an icon?" And any shared resources, tips, and/or guidance would be very much appreciated.

Edit:
I use these sites quite a bit for referencing in times like this. I'm sure somebody will also find it useful. [Pttrns](http://pttrns.com/), [Android-App-Patterns](http://www.android-app-patterns.com/), [Mobile-Patterns](http://www.mobile-patterns.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to what you have described, the focus seems to be not so much on the activities themselves, but on the people commenting on them. So I'd consider:

- A dialog bubble / ***bubbles*** to express the exchange of information and the social aspect of it:

  [image]
- Again with the ***network*** concept, something that shows nodes as inter-related units:

  [image]
- Simply ***people***:

  [image]
- Or maybe even an ***album***, so it shows all the different types of information displayed (like you said: photos, videos, comments):

  [image]

<sub>Source: [IconFinder](https://www.iconfinder.com/)</sub>

Comment: Apologies for the late reply. Thanks for the input Yisela! There are 3 other "tabs" next to the Activities which are participants, and discussions. They use the people and chat bubble icons. However I like the album idea. ATM I've just left the icon as a sad little gray box but I will try and make a nice little album. Thanks again.